# Sybase SQLAnywhere

Tags: sqlanywhere

I just downloaded Sybase SQLAnywhere Developer Edition and installed. It looks fantastic and maintenance also very easy. Could someone let me know which engine it uses? Is it Interbase? Secondly, is there any RAM or DB size limit in this edition? How would you rate this RDBMS?

Comment: You should visit sqla.stackexchange.com. All the SQL Anywhere buffs are there. BTW, agree that it's a fantastic rdbms. Been using it since 95

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sybase SA has own engine previosly known as Watcom SQL.
You can't use this edition in production.
If you are interesting in the free version see at Sybase ASA Web Edition.
http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1057560

Free deployment behind browser-based applications on Linux, Windows and Mac OS X, with no hardware or database size limitations.

Sybase ASA is very popular in a mobile applications.

Comment: I want to evaluate it for Windows based applications with .NET.